# Including jars in project path from ivy in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, path, ivy

I have a java project in eclipse and I'm using ivy dependency manager outside of eclipse, so I have directory structures full of various jar files.  Is there a simple way to point my eclipse project's path to the ivy dirs and pick up all the jars?

I'm trying to avoid pulling out each individual jar into my eclipse project directory and hope there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an ivy plugin for eclipse:

- http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/

A whackier idea is to use groovy to generate the Eclipse .project and .classpath files:

- [Using Apache Ivy with netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612549/using-apache-ivy-with-netbeans/11617592#11617592)